# How to not print escape sequence in terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, sh

I have a sh script like this:

```
while true
  do
read  -sn1 input
<do something>
done
```

I mean that I will take input from keyboard (arrow keys), then do something (ex: sleep 1).
My problem is if I press arrow keys quickly, `read` can not take my input (it is processing ), and escape sequence displays in terminal.
This is not my expectation.
Do you know how to prevent this issue?

If is is hard to understand, I will explain as below:

```
read -sn1 input    <-- press arrow key
sleep 1
.                  <-- press arrow key ==> display escape sequence in terminal
.
.
read -sn1 input    <-- maybe take input from above key press
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more than one problem, but the one to start with is that your `read` command will read only **one** character, while arrow-keys commonly send more than one.  You're apparently using `bash`, which documents the **`-n`** option for `read` as

```
          -n nchars                                                         
                 read  returns after reading nchars characters rather than  
                 waiting for a complete line of input, but honor a  delim‐  
                 iter  if fewer than nchars characters are read before the  
                 delimiter.
```

The usual (bash-specific) approach would be using a timeout, also documented for `read`:

```
          -t timeout                                                        
                 Cause  read  to time out and return failure if a complete  
                 line of input is not read within timeout seconds.   time‐  
                 out  may  be  a  decimal number with a fractional portion  
                 following the decimal point.  This option is only  effec‐  
                 tive  if  read is reading input from a terminal, pipe, or  
                 other special file; it has no effect  when  reading  from  
                 regular  files.  If timeout is 0, read returns success if  
                 input is available  on  the  specified  file  descriptor,  
                 failure  otherwise.   The exit status is greater than 128  
                 if the timeout is exceeded.
```

Past that - while your alternate script is sleeping, the terminal is back in echo-mode.  Rather than using bash's (sometimes helpful) features, the usual approach would be to manipulate the terminal modes using `stty`, putting it into no-echo mode, along with reducing the timeouts.  That's been answered before, e.g.,  *[How to display the key pressed by the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049045/how-to-display-the-key-pressed-by-the-user/13049263#13049263)*

Comment: Thank you very much. By using "stty -echo", the problem is solve.